# Huge doubt about Quran 67:5

Tags: quran, tafseer

Salam alaykum, i have a major doubt right now.

It's verse 5 in Surah Mulk:

And indeed, We adorned the lowest heaven with lamps, and made them for stoning devils, for whom We have also prepared the torment of the Blaze.

Now, i am aware that this doesn't say that it's the stars itselves that are thrown. My doubt is that it reads to me that meteors originate from stars, which is obviously wrong. And every tafseer that i read said the same. They always said that meteors are taken from "the fire of the stars". Only Ibn Katheer wasn't sure i think.

Can anyone explain, or show a tafseer that says that meteors are not caused by stars?

Comment: Can anyone else help?

Comment: https://islamqa.info/en/answers/243871/

Comment: I know that one, it doesn't talk about the verse and the word "masabih". Actually he says this: "In the verse of Soorat al-Mulk mentioned, nujoom (heavenly bodies) are divided into two types: those that are lamps which illuminate the heavens, which are the light-emitting stars, and those that move – this includes luminous meteors (shihaab), meteors (nayzak), planets (kawkab) and others. The Arabs also call these nujoom. " Doesn't that show that the lamps in Verse 5 are NOT meteors? I'm confused, can you elaborate? 67:5 doesn't use the word nujoom

Comment: Meteors are lamps because they give light within the earth's atmosphere like any other star or planet. As the linked answer explains, a meteor is called a star, and the thing which deals with the devils is also called by other synonyms of star such as in [37:6-7](https://quran.com/37/6-7) and in [other](https://sunnah.com/mishkat:4602) literature. This usage exists also in other languages and even in english for example they are called shooting stars. Your issue is that you presuppose the scientific definition of a star and impose that on the Quranic usage of the word.

Comment: Never doubt a verse of Allah, your doubt is just a lack of knowledge, trust in Allah, He will never say something wrong.

Comment: @ UmH Yea i guess that makes sense. Akhis can you pls look at my newest post and try to answer?

Answer (score 1):

Tafasir are made in the context of knowledge people have at the time.

If a certain verse has to do with something which people in the past did not understand well, that is how their tafsir will be.

I can see a bunch of explanations of this verse simply looking at it. I am not sure why you would be stuck on it.

Most important foundation to understand is that half of this is a matter of the ghayb. We don't know how the Jinn are affected. We can only see the physical portion.

1. Stars themselves are thrown.

This is because throwing is from the eye of the beholder. Stars are moving and quite fast. Perhaps their movement somehow restricts the Jinn.

Someone could object and pretend throwing must mean they are targeted and thrown rather than plain movement, but that's their interpretation.

2. Meteors and asteroids are thrown

Almost all objects, including planets, are made from stars at the end of the day. For example, meteors are often made of iron. How do you think iron forms? In the core of stars.

But, Allah knows best exactly how it works. It is difficult to make a clearly correct interpretation because the verse is essentially about the ghayb, not science. Things could be thrown in front of our eyes and we could not recognize it because it seems to us normal movement even when there is something in the unseen going on.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question bro. Firstly, if the movement of actual stars was meant by "stoning", it would make literally no sense at all. There would be multiple problems, both scientific and islamic problems.  And secondly, meteors or asteroids don't come from stars. The earth, stars etc formed from similar stuff, but saying that meteors came from stars is wrong in every way

Comment: @Usrneym Join chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135033/stars

Comment: Don't have enough reputation it says. Can you just write your explanation here?

Comment: @Usrneym Try joining again. If it was possible to answer you in short messages, my answer would have done the job, but it seems you need elongated conversation.

Answer (score 0):

Mufassirun are humans. They are not prophets, they are not infallible, they don't have the keys to the unseen.

In other words, they make mistakes.

You said it yourself: The Qur'an doesn't say anything of the sort. All your doubts come from the interpretations of fallible men trying to understand Allah's infallible word.

As the Prophet says according to the famous hadith, "[Leave that which makes you doubt for that which does not make you doubt.](https://sunnah.com/nawawi40:11)"

Comment: I think you misunderstand, i'm aware that mufassireen are fallible. But i was doubting this verse myself already, and mufassireen just reinforce this. Because all of them make a connection between meteors and stars, and that's what i get from the verse too. Because it says we made *them*, the lamps missiles. But the stars and planets are completely different from meteors, how can you "make" them meteors?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135034/discussion-between-goldpseudo-and-usrneym).